# Display a 0 in Count() query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some trouble displaying 0 on my query result

this is my query:

```
select book.title, count(bookInstance.iid) as instancesAvaiable from book
                    left join bookInstance on book.isbn = bookInstance.isbn where bookInstance.iid not in
                    (select lease.iid from lease inner join bookInstance on bookInstance.iid = lease.iid)
                    group by book.title
```

Let's say I have 2 books "title1" and "title2" and in my library there's 1 copy of "title1" and 2 copies of "title2" but both of the "title2" books were leased so with my query I was hoping to get the number of copies (bookInstances) avaiable in the library that are not leased.
The expected result would be
"title1" has 1 instancesAvaiable
"title2" has 0 instancesAvaiable
but in my result i'm only getting the "title1"
At first I thought the left join would do the trick but it doesn't and if I replace it with inner join I get the same result.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` condition is on the second table so it needs to be in the `on` clause.  Otherwise, the `left join` becomes an inner join.

I also assume you intend a correlated subquery:

```
select b.title, count(bi.iid) as instancesAvaiable
from book b left join
     bookInstance bi
     on b.isbn = bi.isbn and
        bi.iid not in (select l.iid
                       from lease l 
                       where bi.iid = l.iid
                      )
group by b.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be due to the `WHERE` condition that is chopping off the title 2 entry. Left join is not able to work because the `WHERE` is executed after the join has been done. Try using the `WHERE` condition in the join's `ON` clause itself.

```
select book.title, count(b.iid) as instancesAvaiable 
from 
book left join bookInstance b
ON book.isbn = b.isbn AND
b.iid not in (
select lease.iid from lease inner join bookInstance on bookInstance.iid = lease.iid)
group by book.title;
```